# Moment JS date range filter from start of time to current time

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-dates

I'm using [React-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) to add calendar in my react app. Need to set date range in calendar from start of time to current day/ date. It takes monentJs date object and functions as filter to show enabled days.
Default filter of `react-dates` filters from current date to end of time.

Currently I have added one filter/ prop that enables all days in calendar.

`isOutsideRange: day => (moment(0).diff(day) > 0)`

Desired output : get day range from start of time to current date.

Thanks in advance.